# Where to find more information about xxx.d folders?

Tags: etc

I see various references to "custom" folders in the `/etc` folder, with names matching some config file, eg `/etc/resolv.conf` and appended with `.d`.  Examples are `resolv.conf.d` or `cron.d`.

Where can I find more documentation about this folder structure, the types of files that can be in them, the order of precedence, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where can I find more documentation about this folder structure

This is going to fairly difficult to answer correctly since it is old (and documentation scarce). Unix System V or even earlier than that, so we are talking about 1985 roughly. Plus ... each of the different directories ending with that .d might have a different answer.

In general (I will try to fix on `cron.d` as an example but it will apply to all the others too, with some expections):

- The `.d` refers to the word `directory`. In the old days it was used to make a difference between a command and a directory. Inside that directory there will be scripts or text files that this service can handle. In `cron.d` there is a file `anacron` that is a text file that is parsed and the results are executed by `cron`.

  Or as explained on the [debian mailing list](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2010/04/msg00352.html): "Generally when you see that *.d convention, it means "this is a directory holding a bunch of configuration fragments which will be merged together into configuration for some service.".

  There is some more information in that link but ... it is simplified for some reason.

How to track down more information:

- If you drop the `.d` from the name there is most likely a man page for it. The same goes for the commands inside the directory itself (there is a man page [`cron`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man8/cron.8.html) and one for `anacron`; same goes for `apparmor`, `usb_modeswitch` `resolve.conf` and all of them should have a mentioning of the directory and it usage).

> the types of files that can be in them

This will be stated in the man page. Related to `cron` (a part of it, the link above to the man page has a bit more but this is the most interesting):

> Support  for  /etc/cron.d  is included in the cron daemon itself, which handles this location as the system-wide crontab spool.  This directory  can  contain  any  file  defining  tasks  following  the format used in  /etc/crontab, i.e. unlike the user cron spool, these files must provide the username to run the task as in the task definition.
>
> the order of precedence

Unless noted otherwise it will be in alphabetical order.